# Explain GoogleApi savedInstanceState

Tags: android, bundle

In the Google Api Example Code they have a very simple example on saving the state. I need this in order to deal with screen rotation.

My problem is that I do not understand where the methods `getSavedText()` and `setSaveText()` get called from. I put the debugger on them but it never gets triggered. The whole thing just works by "magic". What other things can I save? where do I find documentation explaining the magic

```
public class SaveState extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_state);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg)).setText(R.string.hello_world);
}
CharSequence getSavedText() {
    return ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.saved)).getText();
}
void setSavedText(CharSequence text) {
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.saved)).setText(text);
} 
}
```

Link
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SaveRestoreState.html

Alternate link
http://goo.gl/6TJy5

Comment: Add a link to the example you're quoting.

Comment: i think you confuse with  onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Tomer: This is not my code this is Google's Code, I just want to understand it, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Api Demo sample is bad one because it is confusing that you are expecting it will override onSaveInstanceState() method than use persisted state in onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState() when you read the documentation, but it does not.

Firstly getSavedText() and setSavedText() methods are not used in this *Save & Restore State* activity. They are used/called in *LocalSample Instrumentation* example.

Forget these two methods you can erase them. Let's come to how this sample works; on background Android calls **onRestoreInstanceState()** and make all UI views persist their state to Bundle parameter of the method. Please debug the code and after rotating screen inspect savedInstanceState parameter in onCreate() method of this sample. You will see *before rotation text* of R.id.saved EditText in that Bundle. Main trick is that why one of EditText is saving its state and the other is not is because of **freezesText** attribute of EditText. freezesText attribute makes EditText/TextView save its state in onSaveInstanceState method. Please look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3afreezesText) for more information about freezesText.

delete android:freezesText="true" or make it false from save_restore_state.xml or override onRestoreInstanceState method and do not call super.onRestoreInstanceState() and observe that it is loosing its state after rotation (configuration changes).

Note: You do not have to override onRestoreInstanceState method for this sample but for other requirements to save internal state of the Activity you have to.

Comment: Thanks so much for your good answer. I had forgotten I asked the question, got to be patient sometimes.